# VBA concatenation with & cause issues as string also has &

Tags: excel, vba, string-concatenation

I'm reading a value from a cell, the contents has the & as part of the string. For example the cell value is "BAU Dev & Production Support-Partner"

```
xCellValue = xRg.Cells(i, 2).Value
xMsg = " This is a test of the concatenation "
xMsg = xMsg & xCellValue & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
```

When I print xCellValue it shows "This is a test of the concatenation BAU Dev".

Hence the & inside the cell has become part of the concatenation. How do I tell VBA not to interpret the & inside the cell?

Thanks to all those who responded. I've Debug.Print and further identified the issue:

```
    xURL = "mailto:" & xEmail & "?subject=" & xSubj & "&body=" & xMsg
    Debug.Print xURL
    ShellExecute 0, vbNullString, xURL, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus
```

Up to the Debug.Print xURL, the & is still showing in the string. However, the string terminates after the & in the ShellExecute xMsg. The problem is not in reading the cell value as I had previous thought. If I set

```
xMsg = " This is a test & of the concatenation "
```

the body message in the ShellExecute will only show " This is a test"

Comment: Are you trying to show that in a MsgBox? The ampersand `&` is an old style escape character for some text outputs. If I recall correctly, it was meant to underline the next character like menu hot keys.Try doubling the ampersand to confirm, e,g, `BAU Dev && Production Support-Partner`

Comment: Unable to recreate the error with `MsgBox`, `Debug.Print`, or `?` (in the immediate window).  Please can you include your "print" code, to make this a [mcve]

Comment: The ampersand inside the string for sure doesn't affect the concatenation. Put a statement `Debug.print xMsg` and have a look.

Comment: @user11198948 That is **not** the case for VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. I needed

```
' Replace & with %26 (hex)
xMsg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xMsg, "&", "%26")
```

It was the same reason I needed

```
' Replace spaces with %20 (hex)
xSubj = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xSubj, " ", "%20")
xMsg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xMsg, " ", "%20")
' Replace carriage returns with %0D%0A (hex)
xMsg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xMsg, vbCrLf, "%0D%0A")
```

For more details, check [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)